# Regex doesn't produce match when containing a new line

Tags: regex, sed, grep

I'm trying to parse the page https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/tt_news/ for version numbers and corresponding dates with sed or grep.
More specifically, I'm interested in the following html section:

```
            <tr>
                <td class="align-middle">
                    <strong>3.6.0</strong> /
                    <span class="ter-ext-state-beta">beta</span>
                    <br />
                    <small>
                        April 06, 2014
                    </small>
                </td>
                <td class="align-middle">
                    tt_news for TYPO3 4.5 - 6.2 (compatibility update)
                </td>
                <td class="align-middle">

                        <strong>4.5.0 - 6.2.99</strong>

                </td>
                <td class="align-middle">

                            <a class="btn btn-primary" title="Size: 2.58MB" href="/extension/download/tt_news/3.6.0/zip/">
                                <strong>
                                    Download ZIP Archive
                                </strong>
                            </a>

                </td>
            </tr>
```

I would like to get from each of these sections the version (between the *strong* tag) and the date (between the *small* tag).
All my attempts have failed so far and I can narrow down the problem to something very easy.
I have tested the following regex which only tries to get an *tr* tag followed by whitespaces and a *td* tag on regex101.com and there, it works perfectly fine:

```
<tr>\s*<td
```

It gives me 5 matches which is correct. The following one also works fine:

```
 <tr[^>]*>\s*<td
```

It produces 38 results because it includes those tr tags with a css class attribute.
However, neither with grep nor with sed I can get this to work. As soon as I include the \s there aren't any matches anymore. Here is what it looks like:

```
cat tt_news_history | grep '<tr>\s*<td'
```

no hits.

```
cat tt_news_history | grep '<tr>'
```

6 hits.

```
cat tt_news_history | grep '<tr[^>]*>'
```

lots of hits (didn't count). Same thing with sed.
What am I doing wrong? Why can't I use a \s?
Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Do you know, that it is possible to get a complete database table dump of all extensions and their versions? in a non-composer based installation you download a zip-file with this dump, which is inserted into a table of your installation.

Comment: does that also contain the date information when the version were released?

Comment: grep just matches single lines right? I think that's your issue there, idk about sed, I think that ought to be able to do what you want.

Comment: [You can't parse \[X\]HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858)

Comment: Question is not about parsing html. It's about an expression that contains a new line.

Comment: if you have a non-composer based installation you can inspect the table `tx_extensionmanager_domain_model_extension`. There you will find a field `last_updated`. the data is fetched into the file `typo3temp/ExtensionManager/1.extensions.xml.gz`. this is a tar-zipped xml-file, which contains all TER infos to extension. Maybe you can use the core-routines to download the file, unpack it, and store the information in the database table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `-z` option for the GNU grep that makes `\s` match newlines in the input, eg:

```
cat tt_news_history | grep -z '<tr>\s*<td'
```

The relevant fragments from the info documentation:

> ‘-z’ ‘--null-data’
>        Treat input and output data as sequences of lines, each terminated
>        by a zero byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of a newline.
>        Like the ‘-Z’ or ‘--null’ option, this option can be used with
>        commands like ‘sort -z’ to process arbitrary file names.
>
> (...)
>
> 15. How can I match across lines?
>
> Standard grep cannot do this, as it is fundamentally line-based.
>   Therefore, merely using the ‘[:space:]’ character class does not match
>   newlines in the way you might expect.
>
> With the GNU ‘grep’ option ‘-z’ (‘--null-data’), each input “line” is
>   terminated by a null byte; *note Other Options::.  Thus, you can match
>   newlines in the input, but typically if there is a match the entire
>   input is output, so this usage is often combined with
>   output-suppressing options like ‘-q’, e.g.:
>
> printf 'foo\nbar\n' | grep -z -q 'foo[[:space:]]+bar'
>
> If this does not suffice, you can transform the input before giving it
>   to ‘grep’, or turn to ‘awk’, ‘sed’, ‘perl’, or many other utilities
>   that are designed to operate across lines.